# Ajax is not triggered after radio button is selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to store a given value into the data base with php after selecting a radio button by using ajax. Nevertheless, ajax is not triggered.
In order to know this i use an alert, which never appears.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){ 
          var id_user=$(this).filter(':checked').val();
          var stringname=$(this).attr('name'); 
          var substr = stringname.split('_'); 
          var id_paper=substr[1];
            alert('User_id is: '+id_user +'. And paper_id is: '+id_paper);
          //preparing the data to be semt BD:
          JQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "ajax/expositor.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            data: "{'ID_ponencia':'"+id_paper+"', 'ID_participante':'"+id_user+"'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//type of response
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                alert('This is AJAX. The following is about to be sent');
            }
          });
    });
});
```

The first alert works fine, which is telling me that is has caught the two values i want to store. But the second alert, which is inside the ajax function does not appear. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try `$.ajax` instead `JQuery.ajax`

Comment: random fun fact, you should do {'ID_ponencia': id_paper, 'ID_Participante': id_user} for the data line. much easier on the eyes. could be why it's broken too? i've never seen people use json as a string

Comment: That did the trick! I changed to $.ajax as well as the fun fact to {'ID_ponencia': id_paper, 'ID_Participante': id_user}. Now i get the second alert ☺. The fun fact i saw it somewhere out there in another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) ajax data is not correctly formated
2)use `$` instead `JQuery`
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "ajax/expositor.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        data: {ID_ponencia: id_paper, ID_participante:id_user},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//type of response
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend:function(){
            alert('This is AJAX. The following is about to be sent');
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax data parameter, you should try something like this:

```
data: { ID_ponencia : id_paper, ID_participante : id_user }
```

That is the correct way to send the data.

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "{'ID_ponencia:'"+id_paper+"', 'ID_participante:'"+id_user+"'}",
```